# Cannot view Activity history

Tags: sharing-rule, activity-settings

I have an activity in the Account history that was created by one user (user A) but is not visible by user B. Both Users are have the same profile and are part of the same User Group.

The Account sharing settings is set to Private but I have a sharing rule that allows for the above uses Read/Write on the accounts owned by users in the same Group. User A is the owner of the Account and the Activity

Activity org wide sharing is set to Controlled by Parent.

On the other hand, activities in the Open Activities list are visible to both users.

How do I make User B see the activities owned by User A?

Comment: Maybe the task it self was set to Private?

Comment: @YuvalV If you mean the 'Public' field used for visibility in the selfServicePortal, then both ways it does not appear in the Activity History list.

Comment: what is the sharing setting of Account ? is it private? or public read/write?

Comment: You don't have a Visualforce Page override on the standard Task View do you by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

In a Private Sharing model with Activities controlled by parent, users can only view activities on the Activity related list if the activity is assigned to that user. Using a sharing rule to open up access on the parent record will not roll down to the activity. 
Without any workflow, the the only viable workaround is to change the OWD for the parent object which is not something we would like to do.
 Activity field **"Public"** (On Event and Task objects) is unchecked by default on new activity.
This is causing the record not to show up on Activity History section for users accessing shared Accounts.
So one way to achieve this is create 2 workflows one on event and one on task.
**Rule criteria: Public equals False** 
**Evaluation criteria: when a record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria**
**Immediate workflow actions: Event/Task field update. (Public equals True)**

Please note that you might have to update all existing Activity records by setting the **"Public" field to TRUE**.

Comment: Public equals True is not useful as this only controls if the record is accessible on a self service portal or community

Answer (score 1):

Activity History is not visible if org wide sharing is private, even if there is a sharing rule. This is a known issue...

Answer (score 0):

Activities roll up to account from contact, opportunity, and I believe case as well.  Is it possible that the elusive activity is rolling up to account,  but is on another object?

I assume that sharing on those activities would be controlled by the actual parent, not by the related account.

If user can see open activities they should see closed ones.  When sharing is set to controlled by parent there  are no sharing rules that could account for this behavior.