# Can a Custom Object be parent to Contact records?

Tags: custom-object, relationships, activities, childrecords

I am contemplating how to create a custom object to hold account information and then associate the related contacts to this custom account object. Can contact records be re-parented or related to custom records? Should I also create a custom object to mock contact and build the relationship that way?

**Background**
I have a scenario where a subset of Account records needs to be private. The objective is to maintain records of the accounts, contacts, and correspondence without the rest of the organization seeing sensitive information.

I originally thought that changing the OWD on Account to private and then creating some sharing rules would make this easy. Then existing reports on Accounts with related Activities wouldn't work. I came across articles stating that this is a known issue and the security model of the Parent (Account) controls the child (Activity):
[Cannot view Activity history](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83088/cannot-view-activity-history) 
AND
[Activity HIstory Visibility](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gS3UAAU). Thus the foray into creating clones of Account and Contact. If I go down this route of creating mock Account and Contact custom objects, are there any pitfalls that the community would foresee? I am not feeling optimistic that this will work. For example this point From [Notes on Enabling Activities for Custom Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_activities_for_custom_objects.htm) seems like a potential deal-breaker:

> The ability to send emails or create mail merge documents is available for activities on custom objects. The email must be sent to a contact or lead.

Maybe the custom account object can be a parent to Contact records and the OWD on custom object is private. Just need to figure out if Contact records can be re-parented to custom account object. Or, maintain existing Account records and Account - Contact relationship, but create custom account object and maintain private activities/correspondence through this custom object?

Answer (score 3):

A Custom object can not be a parent to a standard object. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/relationships_among_objects.htm